# I would like to borrow revtex's amazing footnote and bibtex macros

Tags: bibtex, revtex

Anybody know how `revtex` accomplishes its amazing citation handling.  For instance, if I have a list of references in natbib using any bibstyle it looks like this [1,2,3,4,5] or [2,4,5,3,1] depending on the order of the `\cite{key2,key4,key5,key3,key1}`.  However in revtex it takes that list, no matter the order and makes it [1-5] even for the `\cite` command I quote above (assuming they're already referenced).

I am trying to write a thesis which is not compatible with revtex, but I don't want to have to hunt down all my `\cite`s and put them in order manually.  Additoinally there is no way to "shorten" the list on first citation by simply doing `\cite{ref1}--\cite{ref5}` as it would read [1]-[2] if 2,3,4 haven't already been cited.

There must be a way to get the actually superscript reference numbers in order by just "borrowing" one of the revtex packages?  Anyone know which one does it? An example from my thesis to illustrate:

Typically this material has been a high-κ dielectric [50,42,51,86,65,63,64].

which I would like to read:

Typically this material has been a high-κ dielectric [42,50,51,63-65,86].

Suggestions???

Comment: Did you try the package **cite**?

Answer (score 5):

Revtex loads Patrick Daly's very versatile `natbib` package for this functionality. You can get the effect you are after with something like

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress,mcite]{natbib}
```

Comment: although arthur ogawa is indeed responsible for `revtex`, the (definitely very versatile) `natbib` package is the work of patrick daly, also the co-author (with helmut kopka) of the excellent book "guide to latex", now in its fourth edition.

Comment: @barbara, of course you are right: I had a mental glitch (and fixed the answer).

Comment: This looks promising I'm going to try adding those options to my natbib thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh snap, that was it! You guys rock, how do you I give kudos for answers.  All the suggestions worked!

Answer (score 3):

The [`cite` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite) provides this functionality - the ability to compress citation lists.

Comment: And (seemingly) superscript cites, too.

Comment: I think I have the cite package included already, is there an option I need to include too?

Comment: Oh snap, that was it! You guys rock, how do you I give kudos for answers.  All the suggestions worked!

Answer (score 3):

You could also look at the `amsrefs` package, which also allows to compress cites.  And the `biblatex` package is yet another (powerful) solution to many problems with bibliographies.

Comment: Thank you for the two suggestions. I am sure one of these answers will get the job done.  This community is wonderful! Thank you all.

Comment: Oh snap, that was it! You guys rock, how do you I give kudos for answers.  All the suggestions worked!